# Date formating in excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a column of dates in excel that I want to work with on python. The problem is that some of the dates are recognised on excel and others aren't which makes them unworkeable with in python. The format is variable such as sep-90 or Feb-1991. Anyone knows how to fix that? They generally all have a MMM-YY or MMMM-YYYY format.

[image]

Comment: There's lots of examples online of how to convert text-that-looks-like-a-date to a date in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Format your data in Excel first with this

```
=DATEVALUE(date_text)
```

Try this:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/